# Creating a custom generator with Yeoman

Tags: scaffolding, yeoman

I'd like to use Yeoman for scaffolding a few different projects I'm working on.  For now, however, I'd like to start with something as simple as having a generator that creates the following folder structure:

```
/build/
/src/
/spec/
/spec/test/
/spec/buster.js
/.jshintrc
/readme.md
```

The .jshintrc, readme.md file and buster.js files can have have just a random line of text.

I've tried reading through the [generator readme](http://yeoman.io/generators.html) and countless examples but clearly I'm missing something as none of the generators I end up with seem to work.  At the most basic level I've even tried running:

`yo generator:app`

Thinking I could at least start there but then when I run `yo --help` my generator isn't listed.

EDIT:

Here are the steps I take when trying to create a generator using the generator-generator library:

```
 > mkdir somegen
 > cd somegen
 > yo generator:app
 ... <answer a couple of questions> ...
 > cd ..
 > npm install -g somegen
```

Then, when I try to run `yo somegen` it fails saying:

```
 You don't seem to have a generator with the name somegen installed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Naming convention I believe.

You need to name your generator directory "generator-somegen"

then install it or use `$ npm link`. and use it the same as you were trying to `$ yo somegen`